# set array value as a variable using php

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I am try to set one value to another array. 
I have this type of two arrays.

```
Array
(
    [0] => test1
    [1] => test2
)
Array
(
    [0] => 351
    [1] => 352
    [2] => 353
    [3] => 354
    [4] => 355
    [5] => 356
)
```

Now I want to do something like set the first three values of the second array on test1, and set another three values from the second array to test2.

```
test1 = 351,352,353
test2 = 354,355,356
```

Is it possible?

Comment: wat if there are 6 items in second array..or will it always contain 5 items?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
$var  = array(0=> "test1",1=> "test2");
$vals = array(0 => 351,1 => 352,2 => 353,3 => 354,4 => 355,5 => 356);

$res  = array_combine($var,array_map('implode', array_fill(0, count(array_chunk($vals,3)), ','), array_chunk($vals,3)));

echo "<pre>";
print_r($res);
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [test1] => 351,352,353
    [test2] => 354,355,356
)
```

**EDIT** : As per comment "**this type output i need Array ( [0] => 351,352,353 [1] => 354,355,356 )**"

```
$vals = array(0 => 351,1 => 352,2 => 353,3 => 354,4 => 355,5 => 356);

$res  = array_map('implode', array_fill(0, count(array_chunk($vals,3)), ','), array_chunk($vals,3));

echo "<pre>";
print_r($res);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 351,352,353
    [1] => 354,355,356
)
```

Comment: Edited the answer please check it.

Comment: both help full... thanks for this. and its possible array([test1],[test2]) key to [0] or [1] like auto key

Comment: this type output i need Array
`(
    [0] => 351,352,353
    [1] => 354,355,356
)`

Comment: @JackPhp : Do you want 0,1 instead of test1, test2 ?...Yes it is possible